# apostrophes changes when I copy and paste

Tags: text, formatting, rendering

When I cut and paste apostrophes between programs (ie. notepad2, notepad++, hiedisql, word, etc etc) and wysiwyg's, and source codes my apostrophe is changing a little. It looks different and it behaves differently depending on the copy source and paste source.

Is this normal? Is there any way to make sure everything renders the apostrophe the same way? is this a windows thing?

I feel like this is a new thing, but maybe it has always been like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean that ’ -- should look like:[image]  -- turns into ' ??

If so, your editor program is "helpfully" changing a non-Ascii right apostrophe into the only apostrophe available in Ascii, the "straight" apostrophe: ' (Or vice-versa.)

The right and left apostrophes are defined in Unicode and ISO 8859 character sets, but not Ascii.

**Solution** Check the docs for your editors to see if you can turn off the behavior. It may not be possible depending on the specific editing software and its version.

**Added** Even this editor in Stack Overflow caused me some problems: I entered the Unicode right apostrophe, and it looked fine in the editor. But the preview window (and the display of my answer) shows the apostrophe as being a "straight" apostrophe: it appears that the font used by Chrome for displaying and previewing the answer shows a straight apostrophe instead of a right one. So I added a graphic for the right apostrophe.

[Blog post about the problem](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html)

For writing software, SQL, etc, you should stick to the straight apostrophe. Editors should **not** convert the straight apostrophe to the right apostrophe. The issues of single quotes (apostrophes) and straight quotes vs opening and closing quotes is a primary difference between a document editor and a code (software) editor. If your editor changes apostrophes and quotes for you, it can cause a lot of problems in your software. You can usually turn off the behavior of "smart quotes" or similar.